# Query String URL without access to destination page

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, query-string

I am trying to auto fill the fields of a HTML form on a .NET page (.aspx) through a query string.

I have tried using:

www.destinationpage.com/login.aspx?FieldName1=something&FieldName2=something

But nothing happens. I have been informed that I have the right field names.  Is this because I need to be doing a Request on the form side of things?  I don't have access to this page.

Due to sensitivity reasons I can't provide the link.

Alternately is there any other solution to autofill the username and password of a .NET page?  I am trying to do this through a link or shortcut on the desktop.

Comment: Query strings don't magically populate fields on a page. The page needs to be coded to read the value from the query string and set the value of the field to what was in the query string.

Comment: Whatever solution is provided would need to be provided by the developer of the site. Or you could use a scripting program like [Auto Hot Key](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to fill in the values. They'd launch the script, the script would open a browser window and then fill in the appropriate fields.

Comment: Thanks vcsjones and mason, I had a feeling they had to specifically be called from a query string and that you couldn't inject them. I am using a VB script to hopefully do what is needed.  Once I get it working i'll post it as the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, without access to the destination page to pull from the query string, this is impossible (unless of course we know the page pulls from a query string already and we know the names of the values).

In my case I didn't.

To auto login I ended up using a Visual Basic script.  Simply open Notepad, copy and paste, change the fields to suit your needs and Save As.  When saving select All Files as your File save type and append .vbs to the filename.  Example loginscript.vbs

Script I used (comments noted by ' ):

```
'Launch IE to the website
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "http:puttheloginpagehere.com"
IE.Visible = True

'delay to allow load
While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 50
Wend

'fill out form with the username, password and click login
ie.Document.all.Item("ADDUSERNAMEFILEDIDHERE").Value = "username"
ie.Document.all.Item("ADDPASSWORDFIELDNAMEHERE").Value = "password"
ie.Document.all.Item("ADDBUTTONIDHERE").Click
```

TO get the ID of the two fields and the button, with Firefox, right click on the field or the button and select "inspect element".  You should then be able to see the "ID" in the inspector area.

Double click to run and voila!